# Como verificar integridade ou violações em banco de dados SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup

Criei uma aplicação para executar em segundo plano para realizar backup do meu banco de dados SQL Server utilizando a classe **Backup** do `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo`.

Gostaria de adicionar a essa ferramento de backup algo que possa verificar a integridade do banco ou se o mesmo possui algum erro. Sei que existe a possibilidade de fazer via script SQL e mandar executá-lo, porém desejo fazer via código, aproveitando talvez o uso do Smo.

Answer (score 0):

Murilo, acredito que o que você está procurando seja os métodos CheckTables, tente isso: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.checktables.aspx